# How can I specify that an XLL function should spill?

Tags: c, excel, xll

When creating an XLL using Excel's C API, how can I specify that a worksheet function defined in the XLL returning a range should spill?

I know that I can return an array by specifying 'Q' as the return type when registering the function with `xlfRegister`, but then I get a non-spilling array function.

Unfortunately, I did not find anything about that in Microsoft's documentation. (Yet it should be possible, since PyXLL supports it, and I guess they also use the C API to create their product.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the return array with the letter `U` (Xloper 12).

I haven't found any official documentation on this either.

Comment: Hm, it seems I am not able to get it working. I now specified U for the return type. My function returns an `XLOPER12` with `.xltype == xltypeMulti`. This does not work (only 1 cell seems to get a value unless the function is used as an array function [Ctrl+Shift+Return], i.e. no spilling). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I am trying to address the problem from the wrong end: Which versions of Excel 365 support spilling?

Comment: Are you sure that your Excel version supports spill functions ? (i.e did the SORT function spills correctly ?) All microsoft 365 versions (version with subsciption ) supports dynamic arrays. You may need to update it.

Comment: I have an enterprise version of Office 365. In the meanwhile, I've found some resources saying that spilling functions will become available on the "enterprise channel" only in July 2020. Strange. Thank you very much for your kind support!

Comment: Glad to help and sorry for my previous imprecise comment: it is available for all *monthly* channel (https://twitter.com/jjmcdaid/status/1217972535326732289). Semi-annual channel may indeed have to wait a bit.